# Configuring RabbitMQ in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rabbitmq

I have a Dockerfile in which I install RabbitMQ and perform some configuration (e.g. creating a vhost and exchange). Unfortunately when I start a container from that Dockerfile, the configuration is not available and I have only a blank RabbitMQ instance. How can I preconfigure RabbitMQ in a Dockerfile? Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye

# install rabbitmq
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y erlang rabbitmq-server

# enable default rabbitmq plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

RUN service rabbitmq-server start \
    # create new vhost 
    && rabbitmqctl add_vhost test-vhost \
    && rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p "test-vhost" "guest" ".*" ".*" ".*" \
    # create exchange and queue
    && rabbitmqadmin declare exchange --vhost=test-vhost name=test-ex type=fanout durable=true \
    && rabbitmqadmin declare queue --vhost=test-vhost name=testq-1 durable=true \
    && rabbitmqadmin declare binding --vhost=test-vhost source=test-ex destination_type=queue destination=testq-1 routing_key=route1 \
    # stop server
    && service rabbitmq-server stop

CMD rabbitmq-server start
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the [`rabbitmq`](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) image, rather than installing RabbitMQ on top of an unrelated language image.  I might do this sort of configuration in your application container's startup, rather than building a specialized version of the tool just for your application.  This would work essentially the same way you'd perform database migrations.

Comment: @DavidMaze, its a dev container, so I need node in it. The core question is why my configuration appears to be wiped.

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process.  If this is a setup where the container is running an interactive shell, or your Node application, it won't also be running RabbitMQ.  That's where the separate container would come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying my config via `CMD` did the trick:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye

# install rabbitmq
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y erlang rabbitmq-server

# enable default rabbitmq plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

CMD service rabbitmq-server start \
    # create new vhost and admin user
    && rabbitmqctl add_vhost test-vhost \
    && rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin \
    && rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator \
    && rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p "test-vhost" "guest" ".*" ".*" ".*" \
    && rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p "test-vhost" "admin" ".*" ".*" ".*" \
    # create exchange and queue
    && rabbitmqadmin declare exchange --vhost=test-vhost name=test-ex type=fanout durable=true \
    && rabbitmqadmin declare queue --vhost=test-vhost name=testq-1 durable=true \
    && rabbitmqadmin declare binding --vhost=test-vhost source=test-ex destination_type=queue destination=testq-1 routing_key=route1 \
    && /bin/bash
```